# Creation of multiple picture albums in Facebook thorugh objective C ( for iOS)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, file-sharing

Is it possible to create multiple Picture albums dynamically in Facebook through objective C, so that we have text definition for album, every time we upload certain pictures ?

## The current code, we are using is as follows :

```
 for (UIView *view in scrollView.subviews)
{
     
     if (view.tag == IMAGE_VIEW_TAG) {
        NSData *attachmentData = [self getImageData:view];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:attachmentData];
        FBRequest *photoUploadRequest = [FBRequest requestForUploadPhoto:img];
```

[photoUploadRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

```
        }];
        NSLog(@"This is Image");
    }
    
    if (view.tag == TEXT_VIEW_TAG)
    {
        NSString *message = @""
           message = [self getTextData:view];
        NSLog(@"mesage values %@",message);
```

NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:message, @"message",nil];
[FBRequest startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"
completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error){

Comment: The current code, we are using is as follows :

Comment: Did you got solution?